# Extreme newbie - Python code skipping to the end (syntax issue?)

Tags: python, python-2.7

When I run the following code, it skips to the end and simply prints "Thanks for playing!"

I'm sure it's something super obvious that I've missed, any ideas?  I am using Python 2.7.6.

Thanks.

```
import random

def roll (sides = 6):
    numberRolled = random.randint(1,sides)
    return numberRolled

def main():
    sides = 6
    rolling = True
    while rolling:
        roll_again = raw_input("Press Enter to roll, or Q to quit.")
        if roll_again.lower() != "q":
            numberRolled = roll(sides)
            print ("You rolled a " + numberRolled)

        else:
            rolling = False
print ("Thanks for playing!")
```

Comment: In Python `main()` doesn't have any special meaning, you're supposed to call it yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Python in itself has no concept of a `main` method. When it reads your code, it imports random, defines a method named roll, defines another method named main, then prints "Thanks for playing". It does nothing else, unless you tell it to

If you want to call `main()`, you'll need to do this yourself. Traditionally (to work with other code that might want to import yours as a module), it would look like this:

```
import random

def roll():
    ...

def main():
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print("Thanks for playing")
```

That will check if the module name is `__main__` (which is true for the main script) and call your main method

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `if __name__ == '__main__:'`, and call `main()` from there:

```
import random

def roll (sides = 6):
    numberRolled = random.randint(1,sides)
    return numberRolled

def main():
    sides = 6
    rolling = True
    while rolling:
        roll_again = raw_input("Press Enter to roll, or Q to quit.")
        if roll_again.lower() != "q":
            numberRolled = roll(sides)
            print ("You rolled a " + numberRolled)

        else:
            rolling = False

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
    print ("Thanks for playing!")
```

For details as to why and how it works, please see:
- [what-does-if-name-main-do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do)
- [tutorial name == main](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sugvnHA7ElY)
- [python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/__main__.html)

Comment: Thank you, that's awesome!  Appreciate the extra help links.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run main

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```